# JTable not refreshing?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Well I'm making a simple program to see how works swing elements. Main problem is that when I change the data of table's model not updates the view. I'm using MVP and I've tried "fireTableDataChanged", "fireTableStructureChanged", "repaint", "validate"...

So here's the presenter with "registerStudent" method:

```
public class StudentPresenter {
    private List<Student> students;
    private StudentView view;

    public StudentPresenter(StudentView view) {
        students = new ArrayList<>();
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Students Registrator");
        frame.setContentPane(view.getMainFrame());
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void registerStudent() {
        students.add(new Student("Nuevo", 1, 2));
        students.add(new Student("Otro", 3, 4));

        ((TableModel) view.getTable().getModel()).setData(students);
        ((TableModel) view.getTable().getModel()).refresh();
        view.getTable().repaint();
    }
}
```

TableModel with "refresh" method:

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames = {"Nombre", "Edad", "Curso"};
    private List<Student> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public TableModel() {
        data.add(new Student("Ejemplo", 0, 0));
    }

    public void setData(List<Student> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch(columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return data.get(rowIndex).getName();
            case 1:
                return data.get(rowIndex).getAge();
            case 2:
                return data.get(rowIndex).getCourse();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

StudentView:

```
public class StudentView {
    private StudentPresenter presenter;

    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JPanel mainFrame;
    private JTable table;
    private JButton registerButton;

    public StudentView() {
        createUIComponents();
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        buildMenu();
        buildButtons();
        buildTable();
    }

    private void buildMenu() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem("Salir");
        exitItem.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(exitItem);

        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");

        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
    }

    private void buildButtons() {
        registerButton = new JButton();
        registerButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                presenter.registerStudent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void buildTable() {
        table = new JTable(new TableModel());
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        table.setForeground(Color.gray);
        table.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        table.setRowHeight(30);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    }

    public void setPresenter(StudentPresenter presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
    }

    public JPanel getMainFrame() {
        return mainFrame;
    }

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your student class?

Comment: Hard to tell anything while "StudentView" is missing.

Comment: The critical elements are know how the `view.getTable()` method actually works, it'd also be useful to know how the `view.getMainFrame` works and how the UI is basically created

Comment: Also know, that using `this.data = data` is a bad idea, as `data` can be modified externally it will effect the underlying data, better to (at least) use `self.data.addAll(data)` - a deep copy would be a better solution, but that's a start

Comment: I added StudentView, hope it helps to find problem.